# How do I escape CRLF in log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I've read the [docs on `%enc`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) and came up with this

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5level [%t] %logger{2} - %enc{%msg}{CRLF}%n"/>
```

if I remove `{CRLF}` it is correctly encoding for `{HTML}` but I want `{CRLF}`

as it is it's printing this

```
2018-06-18 10:40:33,892 main ERROR Incorrect number of options on escape. Expected 1, received 2
2018-06-18 10:40:33,942 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [enc] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
10:40:34,499 INFO  [main] ui.Start - %enc
```

how do I get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not in this code but rather the version, using the spring (Boot 1.5) managed version we were on 2.7, I'm not sure what release this was cut in (found a release comment in Nov 2017), but it is in 2.10 (Boot 2.0). simply fixing the versions fixed the problem